# Bootstrap li item remeins highlighted in white after visited

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing the problem when the Bootstrap item is remaining white background color after being visited. Here is the Html

```css
.my-mail{
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor:pointer ;
}


.nav-mail:hover:not(.active){
    border-left: #007f7e 1px solid;
    border-right: #007f7e 1px solid;
    color: #007f7e;
    /*background-color: transparent;*/
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-mail:active{
    color: white;
    cursor: text;
    /*background-color: transparent;*/
    border-left: transparent 1px solid;
    border-right: transparent 1px solid;
    border-left: none;
}
.nav-mail:visited{
    /*color: white;*/
    cursor: text;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-left: transparent 1px solid;
    border-right: transparent 1px solid;
}
.nav-logo:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-mail-icon{
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:active {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    
    <div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="nav-logo" href="#1"><img class="img-responsive header-logoIMG center-block" src="Images/header/LOGO.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navigation" id="myList">
                <li  class="nav-btn active"><a href="#1">Home</a></li>
                <li class ="nav-btn"><a href="#2">About Us</a></li>
                <li class ="nav-btn"><a href="#3">Our projects</a></li>
                <li class ="nav-btn"><a href="#4">Cooperation</a></li>
                <li class ="nav-btn"><a href="#5">Services</a></li>
                <li class ="nav-btn"><a href="#7">Contacts</a></li>
                <li class = "nav-item my-mail"><a href="mailto:MyEmail@gmail.com" class="nav-mail"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope nav-mail-icon"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

In the code above instead of MyEmail link I have my real email. This is the only item that remains highlighted after being visited. I am sure it has something to do with the bootstrap navbar as I have another element with same link *mailto* and it works fine.

If you have any Ideas what is wrong, please help.
If youll follow the example:https://jsfiddle.net/borovec/aq9Laaew/272810/

you can see that there is a same problem if youll open the menu and press on any item except home, it will remain the white background color.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create a plunker or jsfiddle example and paste here so we will get exact clarity.

Comment: try `.my-mail a:visited {background-color: transparent;}`

Comment: Also explain what exactly you mean by “after being visited”. Are you talking about the `:focus` style here? (`.nav>li>a:focus {background-color: #eee}` from `nav.less` Bootstrap stylesheet.)

Comment: created example: https://jsfiddle.net/borovec/aq9Laaew/272810/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.nav >li>a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to set css for `:focus` 
like..

```
li a:focus {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    border:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works but @Prameshwar Kumar post the answer faster. Still voted for your answer so that other people will know that it is also right.

Comment: Using `!important` is not recommended. If required increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your selector.